# SwiftUI - @AppStorage variable key value

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, nsuserdefaults, appstorage

I'm trying to get from UserDefaults a Bool whose key depends on the nameID of a Product.

I tried this way:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProductDetail: View {
    
    var product: GumroadProduct
    
    @AppStorage("LOCAL_LIBRARY_PRESENCE_PRODUCTID_\(product.id)") var isLocal: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
       Text("ProductView") 
    }
}
```

Anyway Swift throws this error:

> Cannot use instance member 'product' within property initializer;
> property initializers run before 'self' is available

I understand why Swift is throwing that error but I don't know how to get around it.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Are you sure UserDefaults is the right solution for this if you need to store a value per product?

Comment: It’s a personal project so Products won’t be more than 20 but if you believe there’s a more valid alternative let me know.

Comment: One solution is to add `isLocal` as a property to GumroadProduct, another could be to store an array of id's for products that are local in UserDefaults (unless this changes very frequently)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution for your code snapshot - provide explicit initialiser and instantiate properties in it depending on input:

```
struct ProductDetail: View {

    @AppStorage private var isLocal: Bool
    private var product: GumroadProduct

    init(product: GumroadProduct) {
        self.product = product
        self._isLocal = AppStorage(wrappedValue: false, "LOCAL_LIBRARY_PRESENCE_PRODUCTID_\(product.id)")
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("ProductView")
    }
}
```